# how to check that if a username and password is available in database or not taking input from postman in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check that if a particular username and password is present in database or not , I am taking input parameters as username and password  in postman, now I want to see it that particular username and password is there in database then show `"ok"` otherwise `"not found"`.

```
 def valiMethod
    records = User.user_params  //taking input from postman username and password
    result = User.find(1,2,3)  //3 values in database
    if records.equals(results)
      render json:{status: 200, msg: 'correct user'}
    else
      render json:{status: 403, ,msg: 'password mismatch'}
    end   
  end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Authentication? You could do something like `User.where(email: user_params[:email], password: user_params[:password])`, but that depends on what you're trying to do here. If the password is encrypted in the database, then you can't search that way.

Comment: i am trying to authenticate if email and passwords matches that ok otherwise not found

Comment: Are the passwords encrypted? Or is it stored literally? E.g when you created your account, you typed your password as _password123_, and the database will store it as _password123_.

Comment: they are not encrypted

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you can do something like this.

```
def user_found_in_database?
  user_params = User.user_params
  user = User.find_by(email: user_params[:email], password: user_params[:password])
  if user
    render json:{status: 200, msg: 'correct user'}
  else
    render json:{status: 403, ,msg: 'password mismatch'}
  end   
end
```

`User.find_by` will either return an `ActiveRecord` object (user) if the user exist or it will return `nil` if the user doesn't exist.